# Vue.js - How to capture a URL parameter as a hidden input value

Tags: vue.js

I am writing a password reset function in Vue.js.  As part of the process I generate a password key that is part of the reset url emailed to the user.  It is very well possible that user may request a reset on one device but then go to another to do the reset.  Therefore, storing it in the local storage is not an option.   How to I pass the password key along with the new password.  Please advise.

Comment: "*I generate a password key that is part of the reset url emailed to the user.*" How is it a part of it? Example?

Comment: @acdcjunior - http://www.myurl.com/passwordreset?key=somekey

Comment: Shouldn't the user be able to access their email on another device, and then complete the password reset flow?

Comment: @Eric - yes.  The problem is not with the email access.  The problem is to pass "somekey" string as a hidden variable along with new password so that the reset can be completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you can do this with Vue is using [**vue-router**](https://router.vuejs.org/en/) and accessing the [**`$route.query` object**](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/route-object.html#route-object-properties).

For instance, when the URL has `?key=somekey`, the `$route.query` object is `{key: "somekey"}.

[**Here's a demo CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/lrrwkyv7k7?module=%2Fsrc%2FPasswordReset.vue) showing how you could use it.

Relevant code:

```js
// main.js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import PasswordReset from "./PasswordReset";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

var router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [{
    path: '/',
    component: {
      template: `<div>
   You are at '/'.<br>
     Click to simulate an external link user:
     <a href="https://lrrwkyv7k7.codesandbox.io/passwordreset?key=somekey">
     https://lrrwkyv7k7.codesandbox.io/passwordreset?key=somekey
     </a>
      </div>`
    }
  }, {
    path: '/passwordreset',
    component: PasswordReset
  }]
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router: router,
  template: '<router-view></router-view>'
});
```

```html
// PasswordReset.vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p>Hello, user.</p>
    <form action="" @submit="submit">
    Type some new password: <input type="text" name="newpass" v-model="newPass">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" :value="hiddenKey">
    <button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <div class="debug">
        Object that will be sent:
        <pre>{{ $data }}</pre>

        <a href="/">click here to get back to home</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "PasswordReset",
  data() {
    return {
      newPass: "",
      hiddenKey: ""
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.hiddenKey = this.$route.query.key;
  },
  methods: {
    submit(event) {
      alert('We would have sent:\n'+JSON.stringify(this.$data, null, 2));
      event.preventDefault(); // don't submit now, just testing...
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: This worked.  I was using the $route.query.key but missing the mounted() part.  I am new to Vue.js, thus a little bit learning curve.  Thanks for your help.